# Updating scala immutable SEQ with .map functionality

Tags: java, scala, coordinates, immutability, seq

I am working on a Tetris assignment for university where it is obligatory to use an immutable data structure.

**Question**

What I am trying to do is use the seq.map function to go through all the values of the seq and replace them with new ones based on the old ones. For some reason this does not work the same as examples I have seen online. What am I doing wrong?

```
class Point(x : Int, y : Int) {

}

val bodyPosition: Seq[Point] = Seq[Point](new Point(-1,0), new Point(0,0), new Point(1,0), new Point(2,0))
bodyPosition.map(map => {new Point(-map.y, map.x)})
```

The data inside the seq stays the same.

Comment: Yeah because it is immutable, that is the point. But, if you look close to the (documentation)[https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html] you will see that `map`returns a new collection, so you simply have to assign that to some variable like `val newBodyPosition = bodyPosition.map(...)`

Comment: BTW, you do not need the braces inside the `map` that looks horrible. You either `seq.map(x => y)` or `seq.map { x => y }` - Also, that `Point` should probably be a **case class**.

Comment: you should provide an example of usage of such evaluations then we could help you out with applying of immutable collections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Yeah because it is immutable, that is the point. But, if you look close to the [documentation](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html) you will see that map returns a new collection, so you simply have to assign that to some variable –Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez"

```
base class Point(x : Int, y : Int){}

class Gamelogic(){
  val bodyPosition: Seq[Point] = Seq[Point](new Point(-1,0),
             new Point(0,0), new Point(1,0), new Point(2,0))
        
  val newBodyPosition = bodyPosition.map(map => {new Point(-map.y, map.x)})
}
```